# Spring JDBC Oracle Session changed under the thread

Tags: oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I would like to use ORACLE DBMS_ALERT package in Spring for receiving signals from database.

In pl/sql the following code receives one message if available in 10 seconds:

```
DECLARE 
  name VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR);
  message VARCHAR2(1800 CHAR);
  status NUMBER;
BEGIN

    DBMS_ALERT.REGISTER('mytopic');
  
    DBMS_ALERT.WAITANY(name, message, status, 10);
   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('name: '||name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('status: '||status);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('message: "'||message||'"');

END;
```

In my Java code I try to receive messages with the floowing code:

```
private static final String TOPIC = "NAME";
    private static final String MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";
    private static final String STATUS = "STATUS";
    private static final String TIMEOUT = "TIMEOUT";

    public static final String CALL_DBMS_ALERT_REGISTER = "{ CALL DBMS_ALERT.REGISTER(?) }";
    public static final String CALL_DBMS_ALERT_WAITANY = "{ CALL DBMS_ALERT.WAITANY(?, ?, ?, ?) }";

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    public DbmsAlertRepository(final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void dbmsAlertRegister(final String topic) {
        final List<SqlParameter> parameters = new ArrayList();
        parameters.add(new SqlParameter(TOPIC, Types.VARCHAR));

        final Map<String, Object> resultData = jdbcTemplate.call(connection -> {
            final CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(CALL_DBMS_ALERT_REGISTER);
            callableStatement.setString(1, topic);
            return callableStatement;
        }, parameters);
        logger.trace("DBMS_ALERT.REGISTER output: {}", resultData);
    }

    public Optional<DbmsAlertMessage> dbmsAlertWaitAny(final int timeout) {
        final List<SqlParameter> parameters = new ArrayList();
        final Optional<DbmsAlertMessage> result;
        parameters.add(new SqlOutParameter(TOPIC, Types.VARCHAR));
        parameters.add(new SqlOutParameter(MESSAGE, Types.VARCHAR));
        parameters.add(new SqlOutParameter(STATUS, Types.NUMERIC));
        parameters.add(new SqlParameter(TIMEOUT, Types.NUMERIC));

        final Map<String, Object> resultData = jdbcTemplate.call(connection -> {
            final CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(CALL_DBMS_ALERT_WAITANY);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NUMERIC);
            callableStatement.setInt(4, timeout);
            return callableStatement;
        }, parameters);

        logger.trace("DBMS_ALERT.WAITANY output: {}", resultData);

        final int status = BigDecimal.class.cast(resultData.get(STATUS)).intValue();
        if (status == 1) {
            result = Optional.empty();
        } else {
            result = Optional.of(
                    new DbmsAlertMessage(
                            String.class.cast(resultData.get(TOPIC)),
                            String.class.cast(resultData.get(MESSAGE))
                    )
            );
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And I call the above code by an infinite loop in a background thread:

```
public void run() {
    dbmsAlertRepository.dbmsAlertRegister("mytopic");

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        final Try<Optional<DbmsAlertMessage>> message = Try.of(() -> dbmsAlertRepository.dbmsAlertWaitAny(DBMS_ALERT_TIMEOUT));
        message.onSuccess(msg -> {
            msg.ifPresent(alertMessage -> {
                final DbmsAlertMessageProcessTask task = new DbmsAlertMessageProcessTask(alertMessage);
                threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(task);
            });
        });
        message.onFailure(e -> {
           logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        });
    }
}
```

It works, but sometimes I get the following error:

```
2020-12-23 09:52:57.199 DEBUG 20206 --- [s-alert-watch-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Calling stored procedure
2020-12-23 09:52:57.294  INFO 20206 --- [s-alert-watch-1] h.e.common.service.DbmsAlertService      : Message arrived: Failure(org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [72000]; error code [20000]; ORA-20000: ORU-10024: there are no alerts registered.
ORA-06512: a(z) "SYS.DBMS_ALERT", helyen a(z) 295. sornál
ORA-06512: a(z) helyen a(z) 1. sornál
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: ORU-10024: there are no alerts registered.
ORA-06512: a(z) "SYS.DBMS_ALERT", helyen a(z) 295. sornál
ORA-06512: a(z) helyen a(z) 1. sornál
```

It seems to me that Oracle session is changed. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions will inevitably end for one reason or the other. For example, if the RDBMS crashes/restarts, then your session is invalid. While you cannot ensure that session expirals will not happen, you can make sure that your code recovers. As we can see, this code has its own thread. So, the other part of the code, which runs the thread could synchronize and whenever this thread is joined into the parent thread, you would restart it.

This would mean that the thread you use as a parent of this thread would certainly not be the main thread, so, you might have to change your threading strategy a bit.

Comment: I use a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to execute each thread, I don't think it is possible to create an own main thread in threadpoolexecutor